# Where is the compression for this sound wave?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

I was given this question for high schoolers - which I'm a bit embarrassed I can't answer.

> Fig. 1 shows the equilibrium positions of 14 equally spaced air
> molecules, labelled 1 to 14, along a line AB. The separation between
> two adjacent equilibrium positions is
> 0.020 m.
>
> When a point source of sound located on the left of A is switched on,
> a sinusoidal sound wave travels through the air at a speed of 343 m
> $s^{−1}$.
>
> At time t = 0 s, air molecule 4 is at its maximum displacement towards
> the right from its equilibrium position, while air molecule 8 is the
> closest molecule that is at its maximum displacement towards the left.

[image]

> Determine the wavelength

Here is my attempt and reasoning.

**Step 1:** Draw on the given displacements

[image]

**Step 2:** Deduce more information

This is the part I'm becoming a bit weirded out by. Would that mean point 3 also has maximum displacement but to the right?

[image]

Or is it more like this? I don't get why there should be an air particle of no movement in the middle though.

[image]

**Step 3:** Deduce the wavelength

I'm not sure exactly where the wave starts or ends (as I'm not sure which diagram is correct). Is this correct?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the dots in you diagram as the centre of mass of a small volume element containing a number of molecules (but to necessarily the same molecules) defined when there is no sound wave.
As a sound wave traverses the region the position and shape of that volume element changes.
The simple diagram of a sound wave below, a "photograph" of a sound wave at an instant of time, shows the displacement of the centre of mass of the volume elements from their position when there was no sound wave present.

[image]

Note that in a region where there is a compression $C$, the increase in pressure above atmospheric is a maximum and the displacement of the volume element is zero.
The displacement of the volume element at a rarefaction $R$ is also zero.

Answer (score 5):

This question is ... unfortunate. Air molecules do not have equilibrium positions, and to imagine that sound waves propagate through gases in this way is a profound misunderstanding.

Of course, the question is not really asking about sound waves in air, but rather longitudinal waves in general. What the question is attempting to convey is that molecules 4 and 8 are $180^\circ$ out of phase with one another, which should tell you the wavelength. I wish they had chosen an example which made contact with reality, though - this is a physics-flavored math problem.

Comment: If they recast the problem as a sound wave propagating down a solid, it would be good. The picture could be the cross section of a spring, showing cuts through successive coils.

Comment: @mmesser314 Yes, I agree. A very small change in wording would be sufficient.